# Is decryption with a wrong key is equivalent to encryption?

Tags: cryptography

I was wondering if decrypting a file with a wrong key is equivalent to encrypting that file with that (wrong) key?

Comment: It depends on the algorithm. Which specific algorithm did you have in mind?

Comment: I don't have one precisely in mind, but I am a little bit confused with the terms decryption/encryption. In what way are they different if the algorithm is symmetric? 
let say that we're encrypting a message with a Caesar algorithm, if my receiver tries to decrypt my message with an incorrect key, is he encrypting my message with that key? Yes, I guess, but is it applicable to the case of an asymmetric algorithm?

Comment: You can explore this for yourself with a Caesar cipher (the answer is no if I understand precisely what you mean). But ROT-13 is a special case of the Caesar cipher, and what may be meaningful to your question is that encrypting twice is the same as decrypting. On the other hand, encrypting with AES twice is not the same thing as decrypting. In cryptography "symmetric" means "uses the same key to encrypt and decrypt." It doesn't mean that encryption and decryption are identical operations. An example of what you're picturing may be helpful here. This also belongs on crypto.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I think the question is about decrypting with a wrong key create an encryption: if you decrypt a message with a wrong key, the message you will obtain will be another form of encryption